# vba copy paste loop

Tags: vba, loops

I want to copy paste data with a loop, it might be very simple, however I cannot find the right way to do it, the following range I would like solve with a loop till row 13944:

```
Range("A40:I52").Cut Range("J27")
Range("A40+26:I52+26").Cut Range("J27+26")

Range("A92:I104").Cut Range("J79")
Range("A118:I130").Cut Range("J105")
Range("A144:I156").Cut Range("J131")
Range("A170:I182").Cut Range("J157")
Range("A196:I208").Cut Range("J183")
Range("A222:I234").Cut Range("J209")
'+26 in all cases
'till 13944
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim i as long

for i=79 to 13944 step 26
    Range(cells(i+13,1),cells(i+25,9)).cut cells(i,10)
next i
```

EDIT:

Both in the original question and in the additional question below the key is to find a preferably simple algorithm for building the running indices. In the 2nd question we need either 2 separate indices or 1 with more calculations, like

2 indices:

```
Dim i as long, k as long
Dim shSrc as worksheet, shTrg as worksheet

Set shSrc=Worksheets("CME")
Set shTrg=Worksheets("RME")

k=2
For i=2 to ??? step 10
    shSrc.range(cells(i,10), cells(i+8,10)).copy 
    shTrg.cells(k,2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True 
    k=k+1
next
```

1 index:

```
for i=2 to ???
    shSrc.range(cells(i+(i-2)*10,10), cells(i+(i-2)*10+8,10)).copy 
    shTrg.cells(i,2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True 
next
```

(I think it's better using 2 indices :))
Please note how I reduced the need of typing by using vars for sheet references.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thank you very much, You really helped me out with this loop! One more question if I may ask,  what if you want to copy paste with two different variable ranges, such as the following:


Worksheets("CME").Range("J2:J10").Copy
Worksheets("RME").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Worksheets("CME").Range("J12:J20").Copy
Worksheets("RME").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True